# Object Not supported

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, excel-2003

I was going through the following code but it doesn't seem to work on my computer. It gives an error: Object Not Supported at the Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MMDDYYYY") = Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") part.

I created a folder named ELN in my inbox and placed an email there with a .xls file, but its still not working. I have added the DOA and Outlook References in Excel.Any advice?

```
Dim appOl As New Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult

Set ns = appOl.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("ELN")
i = 0

For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
  If Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MMDDYYYY") = Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") Then
    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments

        If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "xls" Then
            FileName = "SomeFile.xls"
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            smkSubject = Item.Subject
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next Atmt
  End If
Next Item
```

Comment: i tried your code on Outlook 2007 and couldn't reproduce your error. Which version of Outlook are you using?

Comment: In VBA go into Tools->References and see if you have any lines prefixed by MISSING:. Uncheck those references. Weird errors like that are usually problems with references.

Comment: Tested in Outlook 2003, a few minor syntax errors (smkSubject not declared, filename being changed for no reason, no path for SaveAsFile) otherwise it works no problem.

Comment: I am using Outlook 2003 and Excel 2003. 

JP: Could you attach a list of references being used under VBA - > Tools>References

Comment: OK, but I don't see how my early bound references make any difference: Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library, OLE Automation, Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library, Microsoft Outlook 11.0 Object Library, Microsoft XML v6.0

Answer (score 1):

The "item" may or may not be a mail item.

This might do the trick:

```
For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        If Item.Class = olMail Then 'Make sure it's a mail item
            If Format(Item.ReceivedTime, "MMDDYYYY") = Format(Now, "MMDDYYYY") Then
                For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                    If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "doc" Then
                        FileName = "SomeFile.xls"
                        Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                        smkSubject = Item.Subject
                        i = i + 1
                    End If
                Next Atmt
            End If
        Else
            Debug.Print "This is not a mail item:" & Item.Class 'Some class constant that's not supported as a mail item.
        End If
    Next Item
```

Comment: What would make an item not be a Mail Item? Isn't every email with an attachment an Item?

Comment: *Isn't every email with an attachment an Item?* I would think so, but your code does a For Each for items (not items with attachments) in a _subfolder_.  In an Outlook Subfolder, you can drop all kinds of files (not just e-mails).  I just reproduced your error by dropping a text file in a sub folder and running your original code.  Please try the code above.

Comment: The OP _did_ say that he deliberately placed an email into that folder: "I created a folder named ELN in my inbox and placed an email there with a .xls file" -- I suppose he could still be mistaken, but checking that the current item is a MailItem is still best practice.

Comment: @JP True, but his code works in a perfect world.  If I were to take a guess, I would say there is some other type of object in that folder; possibly an Excel file, not an e-mail with an excel file as an attachment.  It's speculation at this point.